# How do I find my Apple ID connected to my iphone if the phone has been lost?

Tags: icloud

I've lost my phone and in order to access iCloud I need my Apple ID however I don't remember the one that is linked to my iPhone.  What can I do to find this out?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any easy way to do this.

To do it by trial and error, you can go to the [iCloud](http://www.icloud.com) web-site and login with each of your Apple IDs and try the "Find my iPhone" feature to locate it and/or send a message/tone to it.

If you have any other iOS devices with a similar setup, you can check on them as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's isn't really a way. I guess you could check iTunes or iCloud settings on your computer to see what account it used?

As well, Apple's [iForgot has a tool](https://iforgot.apple.com/iForgot/findAccount.html) that will help you find out which one of your email addresses is an Apple ID.