# iPhone 3GS lost and can’t use Find my iPhone

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 3GS was lost and I don't have any iOS device to login and erase the data.

I logged in using the browser on my Windows PC but it says I need an iOS device to locate my phone. Can I erase the data I have in the phone in any other way?

Comment: The big question is did you enable Find My iPhone on the device *before* it was lost? See [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127982) and [that](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/67254) for some options and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any browser to go to https://www.icloud.com/#find & track the phone, play sound, erase it or lock it - so long as you know your AppleID & password.

If not, start at [iforgot.apple.com](http://iforgot.apple.com)

Comment: i did login and clicked find my iphone.But it says i need a iphone or mac and setup icloud account to use find my iphone

Comment: You need to log into your *existing* iCloud account, the one you used to register the phone.

Comment: i did.Is there any requirement of setting up find my iphone or is it built in?

Comment: You have to have switched it on, on the phone